# Matching the rest of a URL for parameters in router.ex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do you match the end of the path in router.ex such as the one below. The structure of the path is not fixed, there could be one/two/three or more levels

```
www.example.com/first/second/third
```

or

```
www.example.com/first/second
```

Usually you can do a `get "/:first"` but it'll only capture the first one as `params["first"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/router.ex

You can do a

```
get "/first/*anything"
```

And you can call `params["anything"]` in your controller to get the rest of your path.

Edit: If your path is `/first/second/third`, `params["anything"]` will return a list of `["second","third"]`